# Git: Is checking out a branch while visual studio open bad practice?

Tags: git, visual-studio, version-control, git-checkout

When I checkout a branch in Git, if I have the project open in Visual Studio the program will detect that the files have changed and prompt me to reload.

Just wondering what the general consensus is with this. Should I be closing down VS before branching to prevent any untidiness that might arise from Visual Studio attempting to update it's state to reflect the file system?

Comment: The visual studio works fine with this scenario. Ofcourse, if you checkout the branch without commiting saved files, you loose your unsaved work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is so common now to use a version control system to manipulate the file system, that any modern IDE should detect and respond to such changes.

If your project file is tracked, it should also change when the branch is switched, preventing any potential untidiness. I know that XCode reloads projects automatically when a project file is changed. Any recent version of VS should do this also.